# Time complexity in n bit array multiplication

Tags: complexity-theory, digital-logic

Consider an array multiplier for multiplying two n bit numbers. If
each gate in the circuit has a unit delay, the total delay of the
multiplier is ?

1. Θ(1)
2. Θ(logn)
3. Θ(n)
4. Θ(n^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Multiplication of unsigned numbers using array of full adders]

If you see the image above you will notice that delay caused is diagonal to the array.
So the delay is approxiamtely sqrt(2)*(2n-1).
Which is Θ(n)

Answer (score 0):

The no. of gates used in n bit array multiplier(nxn) is 2n-1.
So. 
if every single gate takes unit delay, then total delay
0(2n-1)=0(n)
It is of linear order

Comment: How...   please explain your solution